# Java unchecked or unsafe operations message

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, compiler-warnings, unchecked-exception

I am getting the following error when compiling a **Java** class in **BlueJ**.

```
AuctionManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
```

This error is only displayed when the following deserialization code is in one of my functions:

```
try {
  ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(Filename));
  ArrayList<AuctionItem> AuctionList = (ArrayList<AuctionItem>) in.readObject();
  in.close();
}
catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can I please have some information as to why this error is being displayed, and some help to use the deserialization code without the error.

Answer (score 1):

First the message you get is not an error, is it a warning; it doesn't prevent you program from compiling, or running.

As for the source, it is this line:

`ArrayList<AuctionItem> AuctionList = (ArrayList<AuctionItem>) in.readObject();`

Since you are casting an object (`readObject` returns an `Object`) to a parameterized type (`ArrayList<AuctionItem>`).

Comment: What is the best way to fix the code so that the warning does not show?

Answer (score 1):

[user2351151](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514148/java-unchecked-or-unsafe-operations-message#comment23711124_16514156): You can do this for warning doesn't show:

```
ArrayList tempList; // without parameterized type 
try {
  ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(Filename));
  tempList = (ArrayList) in.readObject();
  for (int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++) {
    AuctionList.add(i, (AuctionItem)tempList.get(i)); // explict type conversion from Object to AuctionItem
  }
  in.close();
}
catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You must rewrite ArrayList with explict type conversion (you can use temporary ArrayList without parameterized type).